# I want to display Custom text for the Vimeo video when it goes to full screen mode. Is it possible?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullscreen, vimeo

I am working on a website where I need to display UserId above the Vimeo video when it goes to Fullscreen mode. I have done this in normal mode but fullscreen mode z-index is not working.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Its just a Vimeo video with default Fullscreen button(comes with vimeo player itself). When I click on fullscreen button, I want to display a Number on top of video. Does Vimeo allow this?

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:absolute` to your css, then add z-index with it.

Comment: Thank you! Of course z-index only works in Position. Its working in Normal mode. My question is when it goes to fullscreen.